# Duplicate entry pooling while averaging values in neighbouring columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to do some complicated indexing while at the same time averaging, pooling as well as taking the min and max. To get started this is an example `data.frame`:

```
ID      ID2         probe       chrom   strand txStart  txEnd
Rest_3  uc001aah.4  8044649     chr1    0      14361    29370
Rest_4  uc001aah.4  7911309     chr1    0      14361    29370    
Rest_5  uc001aah.4  8171066     chr1    0      14361    29370           
Rest_6  uc001aah.4  8159790     chr1    0      14361    29370   

Rest_17 uc001abw.1  7896761     chr1    0      861120   879961
Rest_18 uc001abx.1  7896761     chr1    0      871151   879961
```

I used `duplicated` to find the duplicated in the ID2 column: uc001aah.4 has 4 duplicated. But then what I need and what I don't know how to do is have only a single entry for uc001aah.4 and then pooling the probe column (+ some others) entries into a single cell (in terms of excel) `8044649, 7911309, 8171066, 8159790` so in the end it would look like this:

```
ID                              ID2         probe                                   chrom   strand txStart  txEnd
Rest_3,Rest_4, Rest_5, Rest_6   uc001aah.4  8044649, 7911309, 8171066, 8159790      chr1    0      14361    29370
```

But then the duplication is also true for the probe column:

```
ID      ID2         probe       chrom   strand txStart  txEnd
Rest_17 uc001abw.1  7896761     chr1    0      861120   879961
Rest_18 uc001abx.1  7896761     chr1    0      871151   879961
```

So here I need the ID and ID2 to be pooled while taking the minimum value of column txStart and the maximum of column txEnd in the end getting:

```
ID                  ID2                     probe       chrom   strand txStart  txEnd
Rest_17, Rest_18    uc001abw.1, uc001abx.1  7896761     chr1    0      861120   879961
```

I know this is asking a lot, but if you just show me how to do this on the first problem I'm sure I will be able to figure out how to apply that to the second problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
> dt
#         ID        ID2   probe chrom strand txStart  txEnd
# 1:  Rest_3 uc001aah.4 8044649  chr1      0   14361  29370
# 2:  Rest_4 uc001aah.4 7911309  chr1      0   14361  29370
# 3:  Rest_5 uc001aah.4 8171066  chr1      0   14361  29370
# 4:  Rest_6 uc001aah.4 8159790  chr1      0   14361  29370
# 5: Rest_17 uc001abw.1 7896761  chr1      0  861120 879961
# 6: Rest_18 uc001abx.1 7896761  chr1      0  871151 879961

# step 1: remove duplicate ID2 and concatenate ID and probe.
# Note: here I assume that if ID2 is same, then so will be chrom, 
# strand, txStart and txEnd. If not, you can modify this similar 
# to what is in step 2.
dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x, collapse=",")), 
          by=c("ID2", "chrom", "strand", "txStart", "txEnd")]

#           ID2 chrom strand txStart  txEnd                          ID                           probe
# 1: uc001aah.4  chr1      0   14361  29370 Rest_3,Rest_4,Rest_5,Rest_6 8044649,7911309,8171066,8159790
# 2: uc001abw.1  chr1      0  861120 879961                     Rest_17                         7896761
# 3: uc001abx.1  chr1      0  871151 879961                     Rest_18                         7896761

# step 2: remove duplicate probe and concatenate others, get min(txStart) and max(txEnd)
dt.out <- dt.out[ ,list(ID=paste(ID, collapse=","), ID2=paste(ID2, collapse=","), 
                       txStart=min(txStart), txEnd=max(txEnd)), 
                       by=c("probe", "chrom", "strand")]

#                              probe chrom strand                          ID                   ID2 txStart  txEnd
# 1: 8044649,7911309,8171066,8159790  chr1      0 Rest_3,Rest_4,Rest_5,Rest_6            uc001aah.4   14361  29370
# 2:                         7896761  chr1      0             Rest_17,Rest_18 uc001abw.1,uc001abx.1  861120 879961
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 steps using `by`. I use `str_c` in `stringr` package to concatenate  in one string. I assume tab is your data.

```
x1 <- by(tab,tab$ID2,FUN=function(x)       ## I group by ID2
{

  ID <- str_c(x$ID,collapse=',')
  probe <- str_c(x$probe,collapse=',')
  x <- x[1,]
  x$ID <- ID
  x$prob <- probe
  x
})
x1 <- do.call(rbind,x1)                   ## To change from a list to a data.frame

x2 <- by(x1,x1$probe,FUN=function(x)      ## I group by probe
{
  ID2 = str_c(x$ID2,collapse=',')
  txEnd = min(x$txEnd)
  txStart = max(x$txStart)
  x <- x[1,]
  x$ID2 <- ID2
  x$txEnd <- txEnd
  x$txStart <- txStart 
  x
})

x2 <- do.call(rbind,x2)     ## To change from a list to a data.frame

x2
                                 ID                   ID2   probe chrom strand txStart  txEnd                            prob
7896761                     Rest_17 uc001abw.1,uc001abx.1 7896761  chr1      0  871151 879961                         7896761
8044649 Rest_3,Rest_4,Rest_5,Rest_6            uc001aah.4 8044649  chr1      0   14361  29370 8044649,7911309,8171066,8159790
```