# Optimization a for loop in a data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm using the data.table solution found here:
[Duplicate entry pooling while averaging values in neighbouring columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477365/duplicate-entry-pooling-while-averaging-values-in-neighbouring-columns)

```
dt.out <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x, collapse=",")), 
          by=c("ID2", "chrom", "strand", "txStart", "txEnd")]

dt.out <- dt.out[ ,list(ID=paste(ID, collapse=","), ID2=paste(ID2, collapse=","), 
                       txStart=min(txStart), txEnd=max(txEnd)), 
                       by=c("probe", "chrom", "strand", "newCol")]
```

Data set:

```
ID      ID2         probe       chrom   strand txStart  txEnd  newCol
Rest_3  uc001aah.4  8044649     chr1    0      14361    29370  1.02
Rest_4  uc001aah.4  7911309     chr1    0      14361    29370  1.30  
Rest_5  uc001aah.4  8171066     chr1    0      14361    29370  2.80         
Rest_6  uc001aah.4  8159790     chr1    0      14361    29370  4.12 

Rest_17 uc001abw.1  7896761     chr1    0      861120   879961 1.11
Rest_18 uc001abx.1  7896761     chr1    0      871151   879961 3.12
```

I added this `for` loop in order to get the `newCol` to avarage the collapsed vaules that are in a single cell (from the first `dt.out`). However it takes  ages to run through this loop. Is there a quicker way of doing this?

```
for(i in 1:NROW(dt.out)){
  con <- textConnection(dt.out[i,grep("newCol", colnames(dt.out))])
  data <- read.csv(con, sep=",", header=FALSE)
  close(con)
  dt.out[i,grep("newCol", colnames(dt.out))]<- as.numeric(rowMeans(data)) 

}
```

Comment: Code optimization questions should be asked on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newCol` seems to be an additional column compared to the data in the other question. I guess after obtaining the first `dt.out`, you'd want to take the mean of the collapsed values of `newCol`?

You can do that by replacing `newCol` directly with `sapply(strsplit(.))`. Basically, after obtaining the first `dt.out` do this:

```
dt.out[ , newCol := sapply(strsplit(newCol, ","), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))]
```